# How to check the fate of a qsub job

Tags: java, ubuntu, qsub, pbs, torque

I've run a qsub job (`.jar` file) on a torque cluster and seen it complete. However the output is not what was expected. How can I view any error messages that were thrown by this `.jar` file (I would see them locally through terminal - i want to see this type of message to diagnose the issue). Error messages such as a `RuntimeException` or a particular `System.out.println` or `System.out.err`

Answer (score 1):

There should be a standard error file as well as a standard output file. The path to both should be visible in qstat -f, but it is usually the same path as standard output with a e where the o is. For example if the first job's output is /home/user/job1.o0 the error is usually /home/user/job1.e0.

If you'd like to see all of this in the same file, you can add

```
#PBS -j oe
```

to your job file or add a -j oe on the command line to qsub.